# Adding -fno-omit-frame-pointer option in ARMARCH5gnu in VxWorks leads to random crashes

Tags: c, vxworks, compiler-options

Application crashes randomly when -fno-omit-frame-pointer option is added during compilation.

This problem happens in ARMARCH5gnu architecture in VxWorks.

Any pointers in the direction for resolving this will be helpful.

Comment: remove -fno-omit-frame-pointer. ;)

Comment: Ofcourse I shall do that. But, just want to know the internals of the problem so that I am well informed. That's all. : )